# how i can erase an element form list using pointer to this element in c++

Tags: c++, list, element, erase

```
typedef struct  value 
{
    char* contents;
    int size;
}Value;

hash_map<Key,list<Value>,hash<Key>,eqKey> dspace;
hash_map<Key, list<Value>, hash<Key>, eqKey>::iterator itr;
list<Value> vallist;
list<Value>::iterator valitr;
Value * ptr;
itr=dspace.find(searchKey);
valitr=(itr->second).begin();
valitr++;
ptr=&*valitr;
```

here ptr pointer is pointing to the address of the element pointed by the valitr iterator. Now I want to erase this element from the list using this pointer. I have found that list.erase function do this but I have to provide the position or iterator .

Please give me some idea how I can erase this element using pointer instead of going through the list .

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use a pointer instead of an iterator? The above code example definitely doesn't need it.

Comment: I second Giel's question:  why can't you just pass `valitr` to `erase()`?

Answer (score 0):

`valitr` denotes the position in the list. `*valitr` dereferences the iterator, giving you a reference to the value data of that pointer, which no longer has any reference to the list it is stored in.

If you need indeed erase a certain element in the list, and not just go for the 2nd element, you have to scan the list (from `begin()` to `end()`, and check the condition for finding the element, and use `erase` using the iterator to that element.

Answer (score 0):

The API of the list does not intend to have elements deleted by pointer. You need the iterator.

Depending on the implementation you are using, there might be ways to get the element's interator from a pointer, but that is not guaranteed. And it might change later.

Try to keep the iterator somehow.